# git push fails after using git mv

Tags: git, version-control

I am not sure if the reason that I am having my issue is because I used `git mv` but besides that, I have not done anything unusual with my branch (i.e. just committed some changes to files, including the ones that were `git mv`ed).

Running `git status` produces the message:

> Your branch is ahead of 'remote/branch' by 2 commits.
>
> (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

(Only name of remote/branch changed)

But when I try to `git push`, I get the error

> daniel$ git push
>
> To ssh://git@git.domain.com/repo
>
> ! [rejected]        branch -> branch (fetch first)
>
> error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@git.domain.com/repo'
>
> hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
>
> hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
>
> hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
>
> hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>
> hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

I tried checking out the remote branch that I am trying to push to and looking at the `log`, but the latest commit is indeed two commits ago in the branch that I am trying to push (i.e. it seems like it should be a fast-forward merge).

Why could this be happening?  Is it possible that `git mv` is somehow causing this to happen?

Comment: Git's hint are usually pretty good, "*You may want to first integrate the remote changes (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.*"

Comment: @Schwern Yes I understand that. I don't understand _why_ that is necessary when the remote branch does not seem to have anything that my local branch doesn't have.

Comment: And how are you checking that and how are you verifying you're checking the right remote branch?

Comment: @Schwern I did `git checkout -b local remote/branch; git checkout local; git log` and saw that the latest commit matches two commits ago on the branch I am trying to push.

Comment: That checks your local copy of the remote branch, it doesn't get updated until you tell it to. [See my comment on the answer below for more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33131989/14660).

Answer (score 1):

No. Someone else merely pushed work onto the branch you're working on before you did. So Git requires you to pull their work before you can push yours, to make sure you have a chance to resolve any conflicts before pushing.

```
git pull origin your-branch
```

Comment: Concur. Just do: `git pull` and then `git status`

Comment: But I checked out the remote branch and checked the log and there are no new commits.

Comment: @Daniel Is it possible that you used `git reset` or `git rebase` and altered history?

Comment: No. The sha-1 hash for the commit on the remote branch is the same as on my local branch.

Comment: 1) Try pulling anyway. 2) Are you sure you're checking the right remote branch? 3) If you're just doing `git log remote/branch` that only checks the version on your hard drive. You need to `git fetch` to update the local copies of your remote branches. Git doesn't do any network stuff unless you explicitly tell it to.

Comment: @Schwern Got it. I'm a git newb; I'm used to svn. You were right, there were remote changes.

Comment: @Daniel Git is different and takes some getting used to. Unlike SVN, it's not going to update anything from the remotes without a `fetch` or `pull` (which is just a `fetch` + a `merge`). `push` won't do merging, that has to happen locally and then you push.